# Get list of values from nuke.EvalString_Knob?

Tags: python, list, nuke

I'm trying to work with a custom group node that has a bunch of EvalString_Knobs and I need to get a list of items in them but when I try using node['knobName'].values()

I get an attribute error as values isn't an attirbute of EvalString_Knob.

Anyone have a way to get the values of EvalString_Knob?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let's create two `EvalString_Knob` inside a new tab:

```
import nuke

write = nuke.createNode('Write', inpanel=False)
tab = nuke.Tab_Knob("Parameters")
write.addKnob(tab)
write.addKnob(nuke.EvalString_Knob('prefix','Prefix','render'))
write.addKnob(nuke.EvalString_Knob('suffix','Suffix','7'))
```

In UI it looks like that:

[image]

For listing all the dictionary's knobs of a `Write` node use the following command:

```
nuke.toNode("Write1").knobs().keys()
```

To get a value of any known knob use this command:

```
nuke.toNode("Write1").knob('prefix').getValue()
```

To list all the properties with their corresponding values use this approach:

```
nuke.selectedNode().writeKnobs()
```

P.S.

***`TabKnobs` [have no names](https://community.foundry.com/discuss/topic/120097/get-knobs-per-tab) to reach them. Only empty strings***.

Comment: Thanks Andy but it doesn't look like this is what I'm looking for.  Let me try and clarify the question.  For a pulldown knob, how would I get a list of objects for that knob?  The pulldown knob is in a custom panel that's created by what I suspect to be a pyside widget.

Comment: Hi @Trisfae, it sounds strange)). Your question doesn't mention `pulldown knob`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`node['knobName'].getValue()` to get a string returned from an `EvalString_Knob`,
`node['knobName'].values()` to get a list returned from an `Enumeration_Knob`,

and you can `use node['knobName'].Class()` to find out what is the type of the knob.

Comment: Thanks for this response but using getValue only returns the value that's set currently and not all the values in the evalstring_knob.